# Can't change size of SVG icon in header of ArcGIS Online dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, svg, operations-dashboard

Does anyone know a way of changing/increasing the size of a custom SVG icon in ArcGIS Online?

I've uploaded a logo of my organisation to use in a header for a dashboard. The icon is an SVG file
and is added to the header using custom SVG code. But the logo ends up being too small when uploaded. I've tried changing the size of the icon in the SVG code and increasing size of the SVG file itself in Illustrator, but the size doesn't change at all when uploaded. It seems like it fills a predesignated space and adjusts the size to this space no matter what. The size is set to large in the settings.

Comment: Add a few screenshots and the SVG for better understanding. Is the issue specific to using SVG file format?